# Why I can't embed Twitter in my dash app?

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash

i'm trying to embed the twitter timeline of an account in my dash app. I noticed that it does not work if i put the following code into the app entry :

```
dash_dangerously_set_inner_html.DangerouslySetInnerHTML(< a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"></a>
< script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>').
```

Probably the js script is not running, indeed if I try to put it directly into source code the iframe that I need is generated. Unfortunately, the CSS is of this frame is difficult to set and it is displayed on all the pages, while I need to put it into the right section.